# Passing a single argument list to two v*printf() calls

Tags: c, printf, portability, autoconf

Consider the following test case:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test(char **outa, char **outb, const char* fstra, const char* fstrb, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fstrb);
    vasprintf(&outa, fstra, ap);
    vasprintf(&outb, fstrb, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void) {
    char *a, *b;
    test(&a, &b, "%s", " %s\n", "foo", "bar");
    /* ... */
}
```

The intent here is that the `test()` function takes two format strings and a list of parameters for both of them. The first format string is supposed to 'eat' as many arguments it needs, and the remaining ones are supposed to be used for the second format string.

So, the expected result here would be `foo` & `bar` and that's what I get with glibc. But AFAICS the machine running codepad (guess some *BSD it is), gives `foo` & `foo` and my guess is that it uses `va_copy()` on the argument list.

I guess I'm hitting an undefined (and ugly) behavior here; so the question is: is there a way to achieve double-format-string `printf()` without reimplementing it from scratch? And is there a nice way to check that behavior using autoconf without using `AC_RUN_IFELSE()`?

I guess some quick method of scanning format-string for the number of arguments to be consumed could work here as well (+`va_copy()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer already states, passing `ap` to a v*() function leaves `ap` in an undetermined state. So, the solution is to not depend on this state. I suggest an alternative workaround.

First, initialize ap as normal. Then determine the length of the first formatted string using `vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fstra, ap)`. Concatenate the format strings, reinitialize `ap`, and split the output using the predetermined length of the first formatted string.

It should look something like the following:

```
void test(const char* fstra, const char* fstrb, ...) {
  char *format, *buf;
  char *a, *b;
  int a_len, buf_len;
  va_list ap;

  va_start(ap, fstrb);
  a_len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fstra, ap);
  va_end(ap);

  asprintf(&format, "%s%s", fstra, fstrb);

  va_start(ap, fstrb);
  buf_len = vasprintf(&buf, format, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  free(format);

  a = malloc(a_len + 1);
  memcpy(a, buf, a_len);
  a[a_len] = '\0';

  b = malloc(buf_len - a_len + 1);
  memcpy(b, buf + a_len, buf_len - a_len);
  b[buf_len - a_len] = '\0';
  free(buf);
}
```

As also discussed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147733/429091), this approach does not separate positional `printf`-style placeholders (`"%1$s. I repeat, %1$s."`). So the documentation for the interface should clearly state that both format strings share the same positional placeholder namespace—and that if one of the format strings uses positional placeholders then both must.

Answer (score 4):

When you call one of the `v*printf` functions, this uses `va_arg` which means the value of `ap` is indeterminate on return.

The relevant bit lies in section `7.19.6.8 The vfprintf function` in C99, which references the footnote:

> `As the functions vfprintf, vfscanf, vprintf, vscanf, vsnprintf, vsprintf, and vsscanf invoke the`va_arg`macro, the value of`arg`after the return is indeterminate.`

This has survived to the latest draft of C1x I have as well, so I suspect it's not going to change quickly.

There is no portable way to do what you're attempting using the higher-level `v*printf` functions although you *could* resort to using the lower level stuff.

The standard is very clear in that a called function using `va_arg` on a `va_list` variable renders it indeterminate in the caller. From C99 `7.15 Variable Arguments <stdarg.h>`:

> `The object ap may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the va_end macro prior to any further reference to ap.`

However, the value of `ap` when using `va_arg` on it within a single function *is* determinate (otherwise the whole variable arguments processing would fall apart). So you could write a single function which processed both format strings in turn, with these lower-level functions.

With the higher level stuff (as per the footnote), you are required to `va_end/va_start` to put the `ap` variable back in a determinate state and this will unfortunately reset to the start of the parameter list.

I'm not sure how much of a simplification your provided example code is but, if that's close to reality, you can acheive the same result by just combining the two format strings beforehand and using that to pass to `vprintf`, something like:

```
void test(const char* fstra, const char* fstrb, ...) {
    char big_honkin_buff[1024]; // Example, don't really do this.
    va_list ap;

    strcpy (big_honkin_buff, fstra);
    strcat (big_honkin_buff, fstrb);

    va_start(ap, big_honkin_buff);
    vprintf(big_honkin_buff, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not entirely correct in your last sentence. A portable way would be to re-implement `v*printf()` completely to use two format strings at once and grab the args directly.

Comment: @Michal, good point. I've clarified it to limit that statement to the higher level functions listed in the footnote.

Comment: Well, I thought about concatenation and that's probably what I end up using. But I think there's no way of separating the two results (I'm using `vasprintf()` in the actual code) without risking that the same sep being returned by one of the '%s' formats.

Comment: -1 for unsafe use of `strcpy` and `strcat` even with the comments. This could easily have been replaced by `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s", fmta, fmtb);` ... but note that it could still invoke UB if the format strings use `%N$` argument specifiers and the result does not fit in the buffer. Also see my answer for a very easy portable solution.

Comment: This answer is the closest you'll get, modulo the buffer overflow.

Comment: I'm fine with history lessons but please make it clear if and where you intend to present an actual solution to the problem of the author.

Comment: Yosef, like many of my answers,tis first explains why the OP's code didn't work, then goes on to provide code that will work. The history lesson, as you put it, is a reference to the standard, the definitive document when discussing rhe language. I make no apologies for the completeness or educational value of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the other answers, which are correct, a word about what happens in common implementations.

In 32bit Linux (and I think Windows too), passing the same `ap` to two functions actually works.
This is because the `va_list` is just a pointer to the place on the stack where the parameters are. `v*rintf` functions get it, but don't change it (they can't, it's passed by value).

In 64bit Linux (don't know about Windows), it doesn't work.
`va_list` is a struct, and `v*printf` gets a pointer to it (because actually it's an array of size 1 of structs). When arguments are consumed, the struct is modified. So another call to `v*printf` will get the parameters not from the start, but after the last one consumed.

Of course, this doesn't mean you should use a `va_list` twice in 32bit Linux. It's undefined behavior, which happens to work in some implementations. Don't rely on it.