# Why isn't writing to a file working with variable arguments?

Tags: c

I have the following code which writes to both `stderr` and a file:

```
int 
main(void)
{

    log_init();
    log_add_file("log.txt");
    log_info("Hello '%s' -- %d", "Something", 123);
}
```

I am opening the file as follows:

```
void log_add_file(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "There was an error opening the file '%s'", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Logger.handlers[Logger.num_handlers++] = fp; // Logger.handlers[0] = stderr;
}
```

And I am printing as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i < Logger.num_handlers; i++)
    vfprintf(Logger.handlers[i], output, args);
```

It works fine in `stderr` but its very buggy when writing the variable arguments to a file. Here is what it looks like:

```
// log.txt -- bad
[INFO] Thu Mar 18 23:13:17 2021 - log.c:main:120 - Hello 'H�}�H��' -- -368855224

// stderr -- correct
[INFO] Thu Mar 18 23:13:17 2021 - log.c:main:120 - Hello 'Something' -- 123
```

What's going on with the formatting here? It seems also that the `vfprintf` dirties the output/args on writing. For example, just doing this:

```
    vfprintf(Logger.handlers[0], output, args);
    vfprintf(Logger.handlers[0], output, args);
```

Gives me:

```
[INFO] Thu Mar 18 23:19:46 2021 - log.c:main:122 - Hello 'Something' -- 123
[INFO] Thu Mar 18 23:19:46 2021 - log.c:main:122 - Hello 'H�}�H��' -- -486025400
```

Comment: Where is your `log_info` function?

Comment: Would you _please_ stop editing out important bits of your code and just show the whole function?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @paddy sure let me try and add some more details to it.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: However, please try to also turn the question into one others could also have answered. That way others will find it easier to decide whether your answer also helps them with their problem.

Comment: This is ridiculous.  You've been asked twice to simply show your entire function.  Then you post a half solution showing only part of what is presumably the function.  What is the actual point in asking for help if you don't show the part that's broken?

Comment: C17 7.16(3): "The object
ap may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro
with parameter ap , the value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the
va_end macro prior to any further reference to ap."  So passing your `va_list` to `vfprintf` does indeed "dirty" it; if you want to pass the same `va_list` to two function calls you have to `va_end` and `va_start` again, or else `va_copy` it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a single argument list to two v\*printf() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147700/passing-a-single-argument-list-to-two-vprintf-calls)